# Fazer a CallBack executar diretamente

Tags: javascript

Peguei uma API do BootBox apenas para o *prompt*, mas o problema é que nessa sintaxe tem uma *callback* e, com isso, ele só executa o codigo na segunda vez que eu clico no botão. Logicamente, queria que ele executasse no primeiro clique. (com o *prompt* normal no JavaScript funciona como eu quero, mas é horrível esse *prompt*)

Segue o código:

```
function valida2(){
  bootbox.prompt({
    title: "This is a prompt with a number input!",
    inputType: 'number',
    callback: function (result) {
         Tips = parseInt(result);
         console.log(Tips);


    }
});
}


//a função que chama esse prompt
function ccck(){ 

 valida2();
 myArray[count] = [count + 1, 1 , Tips, "-"];
 sum += Tips;  
}
```

Comment: a questao é que o codigo continua, "nao espera o executar da callback". Acho que eu ainda nao entendi bem como funciona, por isso nao estou conseguindo implementar

Answer (score 0):

Como disseste e bem *"a questao é que o codigo continua"*, por isso tens de redirecionar o fluxo da aplicação para continuar depois da callback:

```js
function valida2(done) {
  bootbox.prompt({
    title: "This is a prompt with a number input!",
    inputType: 'number',
    callback: done
  });
}


//a função que chama esse prompt
function ccck() {

  valida2(function(result) {
    // o fluxo da aplicação continua aqui:
    var Tips = parseInt(result);
    myArray[count] = [count + 1, 1, Tips, "-"];
    sum += Tips;
  });

}
```

Assim o teu código continua dentro da callback, ou seja quando o resultado estiver disponivel.